# What is the difference between the Point and Vector3 geometry message if they're exactly the same?

Tags: ros

I'm pretty new to ROS but I was manipulating a custom message that was made up of `geometry_msgs/Point` and `geometry_msgs/Vector3` messages. When I printed out the message I noticed that both the `Point` and the `Vector3` had the same 3 attributes (`x`, `y`, and `z`) and this made me curious because it seemed redundant... right?

Upon further digging in the source code, it turns out the `Point` and the `Vector3` are exactly the same. They're both composed of a `float x`, `float y`, and a `float z`.

But after reading the [docs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Vector3.html), it seems like there IS a difference between these two messages. The docs mention that a Point should be used if the user wants to apply a translation whereas a Vector3 should be used to only represent a direction (and magnitude I guess?).

Since the two messages are defined exactly the same, I reckon if I could apply a translation to a `Point` I could also apply a translation to the `Vector3`. Is there a difference I'm not seeing between the `Point` and `Vector3` that isn't their name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though `Point` and `Vector3` have the same content, the `tf2` library checks the type of message and acts on it differently, depending on whether it is a `Point` or a `Vector3`.

Ultimately, this was a decision made by the developer to highlight the conceptual distinction between a `Point` (a point in space which cannot be rotated), and a `Vector3` (a direction which has no definite location in space but which can be rotated).

The developer did not have to make this distinction, and in fact many physics libraries use a single `Vector3` datatype to handle directions, points, velocities, etc.

As with Colors (red, green, blue) and Dates (year, month, day) and many other things which can be represented as a `Vector3`, ultimately it comes down to the need to draw artificial distinctions to make the code easier to understand for users and other programmers.